# Python - How To Remove The 'b' When Reading From Binary Files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, error-handling

I have the following simple file:

> This Was Actually Written In Binary
>
> By Suraj Vijay

And I have the following code:

```
file = open("test.dat","rb")
lines=list()
for line in file.readlines():
        lines.append(line.rstrip())
file.close()
print(lines)
print("File Reading Done")
```

This is the output which I'm getting :

```
 [b'This Was Actually Written In Binary', b'By Suraj Vijay']
 File Reading Done
```

But I don't want the 'b' in starting of every string (i.e) I want the output to be like below :

```
  ['This Was Actually Written In Binary', 'By Suraj Vijay']
  File Reading Done
```

Comment: Simply call `.decode('utf-8')` on any byte string to convert it to a regular one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following, just decoding the line from "utf-8":

```
file = open("test.dat","rb")
lines=list()
for line in file.readlines():
        lines.append(line.rstrip().decode("utf-8"))
file.close()
print(lines)
print("File Reading Done")
```

You get the `b` because you it encoded to utf-8 and now it's a bytes object.

```
print(type(line))
<class 'bytes'>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `.decode()` after reading `bytes` to convert `string`

```
file = open("test.dat","rb")
lines=list()
for line in file.readlines():
        lines.append(line.rstrip().decode())
file.close()
print(lines)
print("File Reading Done")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('test.dat',"rb")
lines=list()
for line in file.readlines():
        lines.append(line.decode('utf8').rstrip())
file.close()
print(lines)
```

[image]